# Juntar dos listas enlazadas simples python

Tags: python, lista

**Problema**

Dada la cabeza de dos listas enlazadas simples ordenadas ascendentemente retornar la combinación ordenada de estas dos.

Para esto no se debe crear una lista nueva, debe hacerse in-place, mezclando la lista 1 con la lista 2

*Entrada*

No hay que recibir nada, la función dada tiene ambas cabezas de las listas como parámetro.

*Salida*

Retornar la cabeza de la lista fusionada

Ejemplo 1 (Representacion grafica de como se ve):

Input:

```
Case 1
1 -> 3 -> 5  
2 -> 4 -> 6
```

Output:

```
1->2->3->4->5->6
```

llevo esto, no se que más hacer:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

def merge(head1: Node, head2: Node):
```

Comment: Puedes reformular tu pregunta agregando codigo con el caracter de ` suele estar alapar del 1 para poder entender mejor tu codigo

Comment: Nose porq no deja

Comment: En Python existen las listas; ¿Estás trabajando con tu propia implementación de listas?

Answer (score 0):

el principal problema es que nunca has declarado las clases para crear las listas, por lo tanto te falta mucho, no voy a hacer todo, solamente como crear las listas, porque tampoco has declarado como debería ser, completando tu código:

```
#-*- coding: utf  -8 -*-
class Node:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
        self.proximo = None
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.valor)
```

Lo mismo solo que agrego el método  para devolver el valor

```
class Lista:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.primero = None
        self.largo=0
```

la lista debe saber cual es el primer valor y el largo de la misma para recorrer los nodos

```
def agregar(self,valor):
    mi_nodo= Node(valor)
    if self.largo == 0:
        self.primero=mi_nodo
```

si la lista está vacía el valor es el primer nodo

```
 else:
        actual = self.primero
        while actual.proximo != None:
            actual = actual.proximo
        actual.proximo = mi_nodo
```

sino el actual es el primero y mientras haya nodos el actual será el siguiente

```
self.largo+=1
    return mi_nodo
```

aumentamos el tamaño por cada nodo

```
def __str__(self):
    formato= "["
    actual= self.primero
    for x in range(len(self)):
        formato+= str(actual)
        if x != len(self) -1:
            formato+= str(",")
        actual= actual.proximo
    formato += "]"
    return formato
```

Esto es solo para devolver la lista enlazada en formato de lista de python

```
def __len__(self):
    return self.largo
```

Obviamente para obtener el largo

```
lista1 = Lista()            
for x in range(1,6,2):
    lista1.agregar(x)

print(lista1)
```

Con esto simplemente creo la primer lista, te toca crear la segunda y en base a lo que hay podrías terminarlo, sino poné más avances y vemos que falta